# python struct pack speed up inside function

Tags: python, serialization

I'm testing python's struct pack/unpack performance and notice it'll speed up if put inside a function:

```
import time
import struct
from io import BytesIO

def pack(b):
    for i in range(10000000):
        b.write(struct.pack('!i', i))

b = BytesIO()
start = time.time()
pack(b)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

b2 = BytesIO()
start = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    b2.write(struct.pack('!i', i))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Running this gives

```
2.639040946960449
3.0683419704437256
```

The codes are the same, while the function  is faster.

Why is this?

Comment: It is probably because of the lookup for b. Inside the function, b is a parameter and variable lookup for it is faster, since the runtime only has to look at local objects. On the other hand, in the outside the function version, b2 is a global, so the variable name lookup has to go through more steps and ends up taking longer. You can check it by making b a global too, instead of a function parameter. Performance should be much closer if you do that.

Comment: @toth I just tried it, remove the 'b' arg and add 'global b' under the function define, it slows down only a bit, become ~2.70 in my machine but still faster than direct running.

Comment: Interesting, I guess you need to make "i" global too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop inside a function is faster than the same loop at the global level:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

N = 10000000

def f():
    for i in range(N):
        pass

start = timer()
for i in range(N):
    pass
print("global %.2f" % (timer() - start,))

start = timer()
f()
print("function %.2f" % (timer() - start,))
```

Output:

```
global 0.71
function 0.40
```

It may be explained by the difference in the speed of global vs. local namespace access in CPython.